# XPath: how to select node that have a sibling containing text?

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, siblings

I have a Word XML document that is a report template. There are data indentifiers in the document in the places where real data is placed then (at report generation).

The question is: what xpath expression should I use to put table row, designated with a given data identifier (i.e. containing a cell with given text inside), into `<xsl:for-each>` element?

Table cells text in the document are described with elements `<w:t>` nested into `<w:r>`, then into `<w:p>`, `<w:tc>`, `<w:tr>` and finally into `<w:tbl>`. So the structure looks like this:

```
<w:tbl>
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>dataIdentifier</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

At this time I use `xsl:template` with `match=w:tr[contains(.//w:t,'dataIdentifier')]` and Xalan to find and process such table rows, but unfortunately it finds only those `<w:tr>` elements that have `<w:t>` at first position, i.e. it doesn't work for such structures:

```
<w:tbl>
  <w:tr>
    ...
      <w:t>some text</w:t>
    ...
    ...
      <w:t>dataIdentifier</w:t>
    ...
  </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

What is the right XPath expression, that will check `<w:tr>` siblings at all positions?

P.S. due to system design I'm limited to XSLT 1.0 only =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this time I use xsl:template with
>   match=w:tr[contains(.//w:t,'dataIdentifier')]

Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="w:tr[.//w:t[contains(., 'dataIdentifier')]]">
```

--
Note: if the full path to `w:t` is known, it would be better to state it explicitly:

```
<xsl:template match="w:tr[w:tc/w:p/w:r/w:t[contains(., 'dataIdentifier')]]">
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped, both ways did

Comment: Nice Xpath expression, +1